# Remove windows borders (like in lxde)

Tags: 10.10, gnome, window-manager

I have a small screen (1280x800) and don't like to waste space.
Is there a way to remove a title bar and the frames of the windows themselves?
The buttons on the title bare are easily replaced by keyboard shortcuts.

I used to be able to do it in lxde and really liked it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: kirill_igum: if you are looking for local help with Linux please check out the following:  http://lugor.org and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NewYorkTeam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using compiz, you can turn off window decoration in [Compiz Config Settings Manager](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) through **Effects -> Window Decoration**. In the 'Decoration Windows' text box, delete 'any':

[image]

The question [Optimizing Gnome desktop for netbook](https://askubuntu.com/q/13878/667) may provide you with some extra tips for maximising screen space.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest finding a theme on [gnome-look](http://gnome-look.org) that saves space by not having borders etc.

You could also use emerald (if you are using compiz) and set the border size to 1px in emerald theme manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a theme like [this](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/9+%28glenda%29?content=99775)

Or you can also disable window decorations complately if you use compiz, open ccsm (CompizConfig Settings Manager), go to the Window Decoration plugin, and clear the Decoration windows option.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you switch to lxde, you seem to know well?

Another choice would be to switch to the windows manager `awesome`, that is very minimalistic (no border and no title) and keyboard oriented.

Comment: i used to use lxde when i had 1gm of ram, it was great. the main reason i switch to ubuntu is because more people use it so it's more comfortable out of the box and it's easier to find answers

Answer (score 0):

Openbox, the window manager used by Lxde, has a nice feature where undecorated windows are still able to have a 2px border. It is also easy to assign a keyboard shortcut to toggle window decorations; sometimes the title bar can be useful. Therefore, I suggest you use openbox as your window manager instead of compiz, or allow fullscreen windows to disable decorations by adding `!(state=maxvert)` to your window decoration settings in compiz.